# Outlook not reading ics file correctly like gmail

Tags: node.js, outlook, gmail, icalendar, nodemailer

im using `nodemailer` to send a string generated by a package called [ical-toolkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@machinshin/ical-toolkit) it correctly displayed the calendar event, with timezone accordingly in gmail. but in outlook it says that the calendar format is not supported. im not sure what i did wrong. mayb there's a standard that outlook reading the calendar differently from gmail? here's the generated ics file string:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:CRM Web Activities
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:node-ical-toolkit
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Asia/Phnom_Penh

BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Phnom_Penh
END:VTIMEZONE


BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:3a208ff2
DTSTAMP;TZID=Asia/Phnom_Penh:20190925T081047
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Phnom_Penh:20190926T150000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Phnom_Penh:20190926T150000
SUMMARY:New note.
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:do something
ORGANIZER;CN="The Almighty":mailto:miike.vaan@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=Lead Manager:MAILTO:mike.van@clik.asia
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=Mike:MAILTO:sanada.koei.kh@gmail.com
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: updated: i can download the attached ics file in outlook and open the file from calendar app in mac. then it can read the file